# Reference a global address defined in a host project from a service project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a project A which hosts a shared VPC and a service project B.
Project A has a reserved global external IP address which then is referenced by a project B:

```
resource "google_compute_global_forwarding_rule" "foo" {
  name = "${var.name}"
  ip_address = "<ip address here>"
  target     = google_compute_target_https_proxy.foo.self_link
  port_range = local.external_port
}
```

which throws an error

```
Error: Error creating GlobalForwardingRule: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.globalAddresses.use' permission for 'projects/<host-project>/global/addresses/<address-name>', forbidden
```

Can service project's service account have access to a host project's global IP address without any roles defined in a service project for this service account?
According to [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc) "External IP address objects defined in the host project can be used by resources in either that host project or any attached service project" but apparently there should be some explicit role for a service project account using such external ip address, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a role granting access to the project that "owns" the Global IP Address. An example role is `roles/compute.publicIpAdmin` or `roles/compute.NetworkViewer`.

Comment: thanks, compute.networkViewer didn't help but compute.publicIpAdmin did